# why the imort statement error occur in the yup validation

Tags: javascript, next.js, yup

while we run our code the this below error is shown "Module not found: Can't resolve '@hookform/resolvers/yup'"

Comment: Have you installed [@hookform/resolvers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hookform/resolvers)?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [doc](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#SchemaValidation)

You need to install Yup and @hookform/resolvers before using with react-hook form.

```bash
npm install @hookform/resolvers yup
or 
yarn add @hookform/resolvers yup
```

import it

```js
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from "yup";
```